# replace the url parameter with the selected list value in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am running in to any isssue , i have one select list ,when the user selected the option from the select list i want that value to be append to the url and reload the page  but when i user again  selected another option i want that value to be replaced with new value in url and reload the page . I am using pushstate for this but when I reload the page it is not replace it is simply adding new value to url

here is my code:

```
 let url = location.href;
localStorage.setItem("url", url);
$('#drop').on('change', function(e) {
  if (e.handled !== true) {
    e.handled = true;

    if (typeof(history.pushState) != "undefined") {
      //get the url
      let newURL = localStorage.getItem("url") + '?sort=' + this.value;
      let title = this.value;
      let obj = {
        Title: title,
        Url: newURL
      };

      console.log("url ", newURL);
      history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
      window.location.replace(newURL);
    }

  }
});
<select id="drop">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

here i am adding new parameter name sort with the selected value , when the user selects another one i want to replace it with new value .please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL and URLSearchParams API's.

Simplified example:

```js
$('#drop').on('change', function(e) {
  let url = new URL(location.href);
  console.clear()
  console.log('Current URL:', url)

  if (e.handled !== true) {
    e.handled = true;

    if (typeof(history.pushState) != "undefined") {
      let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
      params.delete('sort')
      params.append('sort', this.value)
      url.search = params;
      console.log('Updated URL:', url)

      history.pushState(null, null, url);
      //window.location.replace(newURL);*/
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: his using your solution works but it is not reloading or refreshing  the page , it is just adding the url parameter .

Comment: You will need to use `location` to do that. It can't be used inside this demo